# Select only one row for each "ID" in a nested repeated schema in BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table in BigQuery with an ID field and a repeated record field  along with some other fields like a data collection time.

There are multiple rows in this table for each ID and I want to somehow select/merge a single row for each ID. Almost every solution like selecting last, selecting first and aggregating rows with duplicate ID in one row are  acceptable in my use case but I wasn't able to get any of them to work so far.

To be more precise my table has an ID field which in BigQuery terms is:
`{name: ID, type: STRING, mode: NULLABLE}` and repeated field: `{name: data, type: RECORD, mode: REPEATED}` along with some other (plain) fields. 
In my table there are multiple rows for each ID that each one has a repeated field `data` for itself. In my query result, I want to have a table with exact same schema in which each ID appears only once and its corresponding `data` field is `data` field from one of occurrences of ID in the original table. (or ideally union from all its occurances)

Here is a list of solutions that don't work here:

**First**: Using

```
row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY collection_time) as rn ... where  rn=1
```

*Cause*: BigQuery flattens results when using `partition by` even if it Unflatten Results option is used.

**Second:** Selecting row with max/min collection time value:

*Because:* the value of the column is not unique for each id in my table due to some duplication in other parts of system.

**Third**: Using `group by` ID with `nest`/`first` on other fields.

*Cause:* using `nest` on the repeated record destroys the relation in the record field. For example `SELECT ID, nest(data.a), nest(data.b)` from:

```
ID     data.a      data.b
--------------------------
1      1a1          null
       1a2          1b2
--------------------------
1      2a1          2b1
       null         2b2
```

results in

```
ID      data.a       data.b
----------------------------
1        1a1         1b2
         1a2         2b1
         2a1         2b2
```

Comment: So you have different rows having the same ID and each row has repeated fields, and you want to merge the repeated structures into one structure right?

Comment: @Pentium10 Yes but I am flexible on the 'merge' so selecting just one row for each ID is also acceptable.

Comment: Let's define the cardinalities as it's confusing, so rows means full row as it was inserted eg the ones where `ID` is defined. Then `repeated record` means repeated, so it's more then 1. After your merge you want plain record only 1 entry, or you want all entries to be retained after the merge?

Comment: @Pentium10 I added a paragraph to the question, hope I was able to clearly describe the problem.

Comment: in your desired result  - you mismatched data.a and data.b in such a way that initial pairs of a/b are not anymore preserved. Is there expected logic? so no hard relationship between a and b?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have an easier time solving this using [standard SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/sql-reference/) (uncheck "Use Legacy SQL" under "Show Options"). You would use `GROUP BY` with `ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG`, e.g.:

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(data) AS data
FROM MyTable
GROUP BY id;
```

Comment: isn't there a way to do this using legacy SQL? I'm getting some strange errors about invalid timestamp  value in my table when using standard SQL (while I can query the table with no problem using legacy SQL)

Comment: Standard SQL is more strict about not allowing invalid timestamps. We're working on a solution to make it easier to avoid ingesting these into tables in the first place, although I don't have an open issue I can point you to right now.

Comment: To follow up on this, we did implement some functionality to enable working with potentially-invalid timestamps. More information here: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=730.

Answer (score 1):

Try below in Standard SQL mode

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(a, b)) AS data
FROM (
  SELECT id, a, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num 
  FROM YourTable, UNNEST(data) WHERE NOT a IS NULL 
) FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT id, b, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS num 
  FROM YourTable, UNNEST(data) WHERE NOT b IS NULL 
)  
USING(id, num) 
GROUP BY id
```

it gives you `exactly` result you expect in your question (with NULLs being eliminated):

```
ID      data.a       data.b
----------------------------
1        1a1         1b2
         1a2         2b1
         2a1         2b2
```

If (on the other hand) you would wanted to preserve original a/b pairs - you should use below (still in Standard SQL mode)

```
SELECT id, ARRAY_CONCAT_AGG(data) AS data
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY id
```

This gives you below result

```
ID      data.a       data.b
----------------------------
1        1a1         null
         1a2         1b2
         2a1         2b1
         null        2b2
```

You can test both query either by running them against your actual table (change `YourTable` to your actual table -> `project.dataset.table`) or by prepending respective query with below code and running as is

```
WITH YourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING>>[('1a1', NULL),('1a2','1b2')] AS data UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS id, ARRAY<STRUCT<a STRING, b STRING>>[('2a1', '2b1'),(NULL,'2b2')] AS data 
)
```

Comment: the example I gave in my question **was not expected** was the reason why the third solution does not work.

Comment: Not sure if this means your question is answered or still not. If not - can you clarify?

Comment: I reread again your question and I see now - third example was example of what not expected. Sorry for confusion. So it means that Elliott's answer is what you need

Comment: Yes, thanks for your answer. I just wanted to point that your first solution does not do what I want here but the second one does the job as @Elliott Brossard also suggested.